# What steps should I take to handle an S-shaped residual plot from a linear regression?

Tags: regression, anova, residuals

I regressed difference in sales between the first and last year of a series of events for a set of clients, on various characteristics including first year sales, type of client, number of orders, etc. I found this residual pattern, which repeats upon conducting univariate regressions as well:

[image: Normal Probability Plot of Residuals from Regression of Sales Difference]

The sales difference is sort of "super normal":

[image: Histogram of Sales Difference]

[image: Normal Probability Plot of Sales Difference]

So it seems the residual pattern appears in the distribution of sales difference. (Note the Anderson-Darling test has a p < 0.05, meaning that we reject the null that this is normally distributed.)

I've attempted a few transformations of sales difference and predictors; however, I haven't found anything that removes this S-shaped pattern.

One suggestion from a professor was to use a time-series analysis; however, given the available data, I don't see how that would help, since the first and last years are aggregated (let's assume I can't get the details). We could enter the first and last years as separate observations with the year noted for each client, but the span between first and last years ranges from 1-4 years.

The ultimate goal of this analysis is to assess the coefficient for a binary variable, while controlling for a few other characteristics (first year sales, client type, etc.), with the outcome of sales difference. So the research question is: does group inclusion (binary variable) increase sales? That is, is the coefficient of the binary grouping variable > 0?

Comment: These long tails are characteristic of residuals in many situations (especially when lots of explanatory variables are involved).  Let's turn your question back to you: why do you think this pattern presents a problem?  How might it be affecting your conclusions or decisions?  That information will suggest how to proceed--if, indeed, anything needs to be done at all.

Comment: Well, I want to make sure the model is legitimate so I can make the inference about the coefficient I mentioned. If the model does not meet the assumptions, then the inferences are questionable. I didn't show it here, but homoscedasticity is problematic too. It does appear to be linear, and I know the observations and predictors are independent. This pattern suggests to me that a transformation of the outcome is warranted to legitimize the model.

Comment: What is the model and what assumptions are important?  You need to tell us these things!

Comment: The model is a linear regression using ordinary least squares, regressing sales difference on several characteristics: sales difference = first year number (e.g., 2018) + number of years with orders + first year sales + first year order count + type of client. So the usual assumptions about the residuals apply: homoscedasticity, linearity, normal distribution, independence.

Comment: I forgot the grouping variable: sales difference = group (treated, untreated) + first year number (e.g., 2018) + number of years with orders + first year sales + first year order count + type of client. I tried univariate models too and found the same residual pattern in the normality plot. For example, sales difference = client type (10 groups) or sales difference = first year order count has the same residual pattern.